Detecting button in Angular app on the page from outside Angular code
I'm trying to dynamically add a "Help" button to an element in an Angular-based application that I don’t have direct control over.
The button should appear within a container with the class .submitanduserinfo, once it’s rendered on the page. Here’s the code I’m using:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja-EN">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Community</title>
    <style>
      .help-button {
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      .help-button:hover {
        background-color: #0056b3;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Welcome to Community</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
      <p>This is a community</p>
    </main>

    <script>
      function addHelpButton() {
        console.log('addHelpButton function is called');

        function insertHelpButton(submitContainer) {
          if (submitContainer.querySelector('.help-button')) return;

          const helpButton = document.createElement('button');
          helpButton.innerText = 'Help';
          helpButton.className = 'help-button';
          helpButton.addEventListener('click', () => alert("Help button clicked!"));

          const submitButton = submitContainer.querySelector('.btn-primary');
          if (submitButton) {
            submitContainer.insertBefore(helpButton, submitButton);
          } else {
            console.error('Submit button (.btn-primary) not found in submitContainer');
          }
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
          const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
            const submitContainer = document.querySelector('.submitanduserinfo');
            if (submitContainer) {
              insertHelpButton(submitContainer);
              observer.disconnect();
            }
          });
          observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
        }, 5000);
      }

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addHelpButton);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Issue: The code only works when I run it in the browser console after the page fully renders. When included in the HTML, the MutationObserver doesn’t seem to detect .submitanduserinfo, and the button doesn’t appear.
Attempts So Far:

Timeout Delays: I tried adding a delay (currently 5 seconds), but the timing is not working since Angular’s rendering can vary.

MutationObserver: Even with subtree: true, the observer sometimes doesn’t detect the .submitanduserinfo element when it finally loads.

Polling with setInterval: Polling not worked felt inefficient and occasionally caused duplicate buttons.


Question: What’s the best way to add this button reliably when I can’t modify the Angular code? Is there a more efficient or reliable method that works with dynamically loaded elements in Angular apps?

Place your script before Angular code, and run the observer right away (remove async wrappers), so that it tracks elements added by Angular.
Then, check if your element is added by checking its class list, then call your function (remove selecting element on each mutation) (if the button is not detected, then try detecting parent component, and check if the button is present the same way):
const { target } = mutationsList;
if (target.classList.contains('submitanduserinfo')) {

Try this:
<!-- place before angular code -->
  <script>
     

      function insertHelpButton(submitContainer) {
        if (submitContainer.querySelector('.help-button')) return;

        const helpButton = document.createElement('button');
        helpButton.innerText = 'Help';
        helpButton.className = 'help-button';
        helpButton.addEventListener('click', () => alert("Help button clicked!"));

        const submitButton = submitContainer.querySelector('.btn-primary');
        if (submitButton) {
          submitContainer.insertBefore(helpButton, submitButton);
        } else {
          console.error('Submit button (.btn-primary) not found in submitContainer');
        }
      }
   
 
      // run observer right away
      const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
        const { target} = mutationsList;
        if (target.classList.contains('submitanduserinfo')) {
          insertHelpButton(target);
          observer.disconnect();
        }
      });
      observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
      console.log('observing');    

    </script>

